# Unable to connect to wifi: password not accepted

Tags: wireless

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 on my desktop. I installed `ndiswrapper` and the `bcm 43236` driver as recommended by Luis Alvaro. My wifi network is detected. The Windows wireless drivers shows `bcmwlhigh5`, hardware present.

However NetworkManager keeps asking for my password, I cannot get online.

thanks for your thoughts guys , problem **"solved"** 
Cisco Linksys N600 usb adapter AE2500 does not work "out of the box"  !
WPA and WPA2 PSK are the culprits, hacked the wireless router and disabled security, now everything is working fine  :-)

Answer (score 0):

There's more to wireless encryption than WPA vs WPA2 vs WEP.  With the first two, there's also encryption protocols, TKIP vs AES.  Try each of those with WPA then with WPA2 and you may have solved your problem, as I learned doing WiFi support for far too long.